# Print complex objects using for_each

Tags: c++

I have a complex object that looks something like this:

```
struct A
{
    int a;
}

struct B
{
    int b;
    vector<A> vecA;
}
```

I am current printing out a vector of B in the following way:

```
struct PrintStruct
{
    ostream &ostream_;
    PrintStruct(ostream &stream) : ostream_(stream) {}

    void operator()(const A& elementA)
    {
        ostream_ << elementA.a;
    }

    void operator()(const B& elementB)
    {
        ostream_ << elementB.b;
        for_each(elementB.vecA.begin(), elementB.vecA.end(), (*this));
    }
}

void print()
{
    vector<B> vecB;
    for_each(vecB.begin(), vecB.end(), PrintStruct(cout));
}
```

Is that necessarily the best way to do it? My main point of concern is calling the `(*this)` in the `for_each` within the functor itself. Is that safe to do? I think it should be, but I'm not sure if there will be any unintended consequences?

Comment: Why not have each object overload the `operator <<` and make it responsible for printing itself?  Then you just call `operator <<` on each element in the container.

Comment: I guess this question isn't limited to only printing, but parsing the vector as well. In which case I can't get away with only overloading the `operator<<`

Answer (score 0):

> My main point of concern is calling the `(*this)` in the `for_each` within the functor itself. Is that safe to do?

It cannot be answered in general but in your case, it is safe.

The call to `for_each` makes a copy of the `PrintStruct` object and uses it. The `ostream_` member of the copy will be reference the same object as the `ostream_` member of the original `PrintStruct`. There should be no problem with it.

Answer (score -1):

I strongly believe that `for_each` has mostly outlived itself. I see no benefit in it when compared with range loops. The code actually looks cleaner, more straitghtforward, doesn't require ad-hoc classess or lambdas when used like this:

```
void print()
{
    vector<B> vecB;
    for(const auto& elem : vecB) {
       std::cout << elem;
    }
}
```

Comment: `for_each` can be applied to arbitrary ranges; ranged for loops "only" work with containers.

Comment: @PeteBecker, while it is true on principle, I do recall only one real case of iterating over arbitrary range - between lower_bound and upper_bound elements. But iterating over full container (as in OP's example) outweights this by million to one. And once we have ranges, we won't need for_each at all.

Comment: quite the contrary, once we have ranges, for each will stop being uglier than range based for loop, and then we'll use it more. for_each does not allow early exit, so if you don't need early exit, that's what you should use.